# hide table rows with tds matching conditions

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables

I have this html table:

[image]

I would like to hide with jquery all rows matching certain values, and like this create two kinds of filters.

First filter should check the selected text on the first column and hide all rows if it's V.

The sceond should check two other colums like this:
CosmicId!=null && Coverage>400
I could need a three columns filter as well in the future.

tried some jquery selectors but couldn't manage to select correctly.

A thing to maybe mantion is that I apply jquery tables plugin later on

Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to post your non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/178/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filter1').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr').show();
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('select').val() == 'V') { // if V is selected, hide
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $('.filter2').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr').show();
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('.cosmicId').text() != 'null' && parseInt($(this).find('.coverage').text()) > 400) { // if cosmicId != null and coverage > 400, hide
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $('.reset').on('click', function() {
        $('table tr').show();
    });
});


<a href="#" class="filter1">V filter</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="filter2">cosmicId and coverage filter</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="reset">reset</a>
<br/><br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">Not V</option>
                <option value="V">V</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="cosmicId">something else</td>
        <td class="coverage">1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">Not V</option>
                <option value="V">V</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="cosmicId">something else</td>
        <td class="coverage">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">Not V</option>
                <option value="V">V</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="cosmicId">null</td>
        <td class="coverage">900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">Not V</option>
                <option value="V">V</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="cosmicId">
            null
        </td>
        <td class="coverage">
            100
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```